# Moving computer with powershell in MDT

Tags: windows, powershell, mdt

I have MDT 2013 deploying several images. With Powershell I would like to move them to the correct OU as well. Is that possible?

I was trying with the following but it does not seem to work:

```
Enable-PSRemoting -Force
Move-ADObject -Identity $env:COMPUTERNAME -TargetPath ="CN=$($env:COMPUTERNAME),OU=Servers,OU=1,OU=2,OU=3,OU=4,DC=inside,DC=kinux,DC=com"
Invoke-GPUpdate –Computer $env:COMPUTERNAME –RandomDelayInMinutes 0
```

Comment: Remove the `CN=$($env:COMPUTERNAME)` part from the `-TargetPath`. `-TargetPath` is not the full DN, but only the path to the new parent

Comment: Noting that you are trying to do this from MDT. So I am assuming you are doing this from the task sequence which deploys the computer? Move-ADobject is a part of the ActiveDirectory Powershell Module, which is not available by default. Also the command probably runs as the SYSTEM-account, which in turn will require the computer object to be allowed to move itself in AD - or use a runas-account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-TargetPath` parameter on the `Move-ADObject` Cmdlet is the LDAP path to a container or organizational unit (OU) that you want to put the object in. `CN=` is the common name of the actual object not the OU, so this part of the LDAP path needs to be removed.

This can be seen by `Get-Help Move-ADObject -Detailed`.

In your example the script with use:

```
Move-ADObject -Identity $env:COMPUTERNAME -TargetPath "OU=Servers,OU=1,OU=2,OU=3,OU=4,DC=inside,DC=kinux,DC=com";
```